How to change title value from "My Title" when using NSwag to execute an nswag.json file?
I'm using NSwag.MSBuild to produce open API documents based on our Asp.Net site. Everything works fine except for being able to set the title. It's always set to "My Title".
I've tried this:
{
  "runtime": "Net80",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "./OurProject.csproj",
      // Lots of setting omitted
      "infoTitle": "Our desired custom title",
      "infoDescription": "Our custom description",
      "infoVersion": "1.0.0",      
      "output": "./open-api.json",
      "outputType": "OpenApi3",
    }
  }
}

And this:
{
  "runtime": "Net80",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "./OurProject.csproj",
      // Lots of setting omitted
      "info": {
        "title": "Our desired custom title",
        "description": "Our custom description",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      "output": "./open-api.json",
      "outputType": "OpenApi3",
    }
  }
}

But neither work.
I have come across this very similar question, but the OP seems to be trying to affect the Swashbuckle UI provided at runtime. Hence, most of the answers focus on the C# code.
I am using a build target to run NSwag and write the file.
